# Show / hide text input when checkbox is disabled

Tags: jquery, show-hide

This snippet successfully shows the text input `#typeOther` when the checkbox `#securityCl` is clicked. However, to avoid submitting the form with unneeded text if the user switches to another radio button, or disables the inputs altogether by clicking the `#securityCl` checkbox again, I would like to hide and clear the `#typeOther` text input.

HTML:

```
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="securityCl" name="securityCL">
                <label for="securityCl">Security Clearance - Type:</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="indent">
                <input type="radio" id="typeTsSci" name="securityType" disabled="disabled">
                <label for="typeTsSci">TS/SCI</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="typeS" name="securityType" disabled="disabled">
                <label for="typeS">S</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="indent">
                <input type="radio" id="typeTs" name="securityType" disabled="disabled">
                <label for="typeTs">TS</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="typeOther" name="securityType" disabled="disabled">
                <label for="typeOther">Other:</label><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="otherText" name="securityType" disabled="disabled">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
        var hide = $('#otherText').hide();
        $('#securityCl').click(function() {
            $('input[name="securityType"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
            $('#typeOther').click(function() {
                $(hide).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: So what's the problem?  It doesn't do what you expect it to do?  Also why are you nesting your handlers?  Everytime secureCl gets clicked, another event handler is going to be registered on securityType.

Comment: What are you expecting `$('#typeOther').click(function()...` to do for you?

Comment: @EliGassert I'm nesting my handlers because I'm still learning the do's and don'ts of JS. The answer from j08691 does exactly what I was looking for. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: gotcha.  Ok well that's not something you want to do :) if you put an alert in the handler and click the securityCl a few times, you'll see why!  It'll add an alert for every click and you'll see it's going to be wastefully adding the same handler over and over.  See my answer for a cleaned up version.

Comment: I hate to be pain, but I do personally think using Common functions aliases as variable names is, troublesome! :X Just noting!

Comment: @MackieeE I totally agree with you. I don't know why I even left that in this example and I shouldn't have used it for testing in the first place. thanks for reinforcing that fact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/uzCta/2/  Here's my updated fiddle.

Things of note:

- move the event handling out of the nesting
- trigger the active item events so it forces initial state (useful when editing, if already other selected, it'll re-initialize the expanded other check box)
- changed the handler to handle any click on any radio button in the group, so it knows to hide/show the other box properly.

Here's the important code:

```
$(function() {
    var hide = $('#otherText').hide();

    $('input[name="securityType"]').prop('disabled', !$('#securityCl').prop('checked'));

    $('#securityCl').click(function() {
        $('input[name="securityType"]').prop('disabled', !$(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    $('input[name="securityType"]').click(function()
    {
        if($('#typeOther').is(':checked'))
            hide.show();
        else
            hide.hide();
    });

    $('input[name="securityType"]:checked').trigger('click'); // trigger an initial state change
});
```

EDIT: Two inconsistencies worth noting.  I deviated from your sample a bit.  `:input[name...]` should just be `input[name...]` or I should have changed it above as well in your click handler.  And I left your `$(hide)` wrapper but below called `hide.hide()` directly without wrapping.  Since this is already a jquery object, no need to wrap it in `$()`.  But I will leave the answer as is, as it doesn't affect the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var hide = $('#otherText').hide();
 $('#securityCl').click(function () {
     $('input[name="securityType"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
     $('input[name="securityType"]').click(function () {
         if ($('#typeOther').is(':checked')) {
             $('#otherText').show();
         } else {
             $('#otherText').hide();
         }
     });
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZasNf/)**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use the toggle function to bounce between showing and hiding.  http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Here's an example of how it's used, in a related thread. [jquery toggle - switch between toggle functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121902/jquery-toggle-switch-between-toggle-functions)